# gcloud deploy ... --trigger-resource for triggering on Firestore write 'CloudEvents' needs a bit of clarification

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I read and followed the examples found on [Google Cloud Firestore Triggers](http://%3Chttps://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore%3E).  I have been able to deploy these examples following.

```
gcloud functions deploy my-second-event \
--entry-point CloudEventFunction2.Function \
--runtime dotnet3 \
--trigger-event "providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create" \
--trigger-resource "projects/my-projectId/databases/(default)/documents/messages/{pushId}" \
```

NOTE that the `/documents/messages/{pushId}` part of this resource aligns with the "Deploy your function" section.

HOWEVER a little further down --trigger-resource 'NAME' is described as...

> The fully qualified database path to which the function will listen. This should conform to the following format: "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/PATH" The {pushId} text is a wildcard parameter described above in Specifying the document path.*

Now we get to my confusion when we follow the link to "Specifying the document path".  I believe I understand what is meant by "Functions only respond to document changes, and cannot monitor specific fields or collections.".   HOWEVER if we look at the above `/documents/messages/{pushId}` - 'documents' is a collection and 'messages' is a document.  Following from the above limitations about functions only responding to document changes, I would NOT expect the event to be triggered by the {pushId} event (because the pushId is EITHER a collection or a field (it sits directly on a document 'messages').

What seems to be to be indicated is that the {pushId} wild card be put directly under the collection 'documents'; resulting in...

`--trigger-resource  "projects/my-projectId/databases/(default)/documents/{pushId}"`

Meaning that when a new message is pushed to the documents collection the cloud event is triggered.

However the above change yeilds below...

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[
The request has errors
Problems:
event_trigger:
Expected value {pushId} to match regular expression [^/]+/[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^/]+)*
]
```

While I am sure I am doing something wrong,  I am struggling to make sense out of the above observations, also my function is not being triggered.

I would really appreciate any hints as to how this is to be understood, and or at least how to get my function to trigger on create.

FYI; the 'Function' I am using is from the dotnet template provided by Visual Studio (2022).

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, but if the collection in your database is literally named `documents` then your path is going to look like this:

`--trigger-resource  "projects/my-projectId/databases/(default)/documents/documents/{pushId}"`

The second instance of `documents` is the literal name of the collection you are watching.